# Mock graph mail API Stream response

Tags: .net, email, mocking, microsoft-graph-api

I can successfully download a mail in `eml` format given the mails ID like this:

```
var mailStream = await client.Users.Me.Messages[mailId].Content.GetAsync();
using var outputFileStream = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Create);
mailStream.CopyTo(outputFileStream);
```

I would like to mock this call for unit testing.
However I have troubles finding the correct `DiscriminatorValue` for this mock, see `{???}`.
The return value should be `Stream?`.

```
var mockRequestAdapter = RequestAdapterMockFactory.Create();
mockRequestAdapter.Setup(adapter => adapter.SendAsync( // Download eml stream
    It.Is<RequestInformation>(info => info.HttpMethod == Method.GET),
    {???}.CreateFromDiscriminatorValue,
    It.IsAny<Dictionary<string, ParsableFactory<IParsable>>>(),
    It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
    .ReturnsAsync(EmlTestMailStream());
```

What is the correct method to call here for the mock to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SendPrimitiveAsync` instead of `SendAsync` when the return value is either `Stream` or `int`.

```
var mockRequestAdapter = RequestAdapterMockFactory.Create();
mockRequestAdapter.Setup(adapter => adapter.SendPrimitiveAsync<Stream>( // Download eml stream
    It.Is<RequestInformation>(info => info.HttpMethod == Method.GET),
    It.IsAny<Dictionary<string, ParsableFactory<IParsable>>>(),
    It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
    .ReturnsAsync(EmlTestMailStream());
```